# Arco iris or arcoíris?

Tags: vocabulario

Is it one word or two? What would be most appropriate grammar-wise? If there's a regional variance, how is it in Mexico or the rest of latin America? I have seen rainbow translated as both, even in sources such as Wikipedia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both are correct, and is easier to hear *arco iris* (plural *arcos iris*), but the accepted form is **arcoíris** (plural *“los arcoíris”*, not "arcoírises"), at least [according to the Real Academia de la Lengua](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=arco%EDris) .

Doing [some research](http://castellanoactual.com/duda-resuelta-arcoiris-arco-iris-o-arcoiris/) I found:

> El Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas (2005) señala que, aunque suele usarse la forma “arco iris” (plural “arcos iris”), es preferible la grafía simple “arcoíris” (plural “los arcoíris”). Es una palabra  compuesta cuyo primer elemento “arco” se convierte en átono.
>
> La palabra “arcoíris” se tilda en la í porque contiene un  hiato de vocal abierta (o) más vocal cerrada (í), y según las reglas de tildación del español, los hiatos con esta estructura siempre deben llevar tilde en la vocal cerrada.

Hope that it helps.

Comment: I've never said or heard "Arcos iris" I'm from México.

Comment: @JaimeCruzTriana, puede que porque “arco iris” y “arcoíris” son casi indistinguibles al hablar, pero no deberias ver escrito "los arco iris" (segun las recomendaciones del enlace y por tanto del Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas.

Comment: Bueno, tal vez me faltó agregar que el plural me parece demasiado raro, mi concepción de la palabra es como un todo, nunca se me habría ocurrido separarla (Salvo como análisis claro, si me había dado cuenta del arco-iris) porque siempre el plural ha sido como virus, igual en ambos casos.